# Can I download apps inside android emulator from Google play

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I am trying to download an app from virtual emulator using google play. Google play list all my real devices that I have used my email on and asks to download this app to one of them. I want to install it in the mobile emulator instead, is this even possible ?

[Google play emulator download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE1ds.png)

Comment: Is this a programming problem?

Comment: @Selvin yes it is , Im building a robotic process automation for a mobile app. I need to download that app on a virtual device (emulator) from android studio however immediately when I click download , it shows my real devices instead of the emulator to download to. . .

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible,

- Open the AVD manager in android studio
- create a virtual device
- choose a device definition with the play store icon [image: sreenshot of device definition]

Using this AVD you'll be able to login and access the play store. You can then install apps on this device via the browser too

Comment: cool let me try that. Just to confirm , if you emulator does not have the playstore icon then you cannot achieve this even if you access playstore using the browser ?

Comment: For some reason no emulator configs show the google play store option...

Comment: From the emulator, it says the device is not compatible though. (My app) Is there another requirement that I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator having the "PlayStore" then you can sign with your Gmail account, and can download the app likewise the real device,

Comment: I accessed Google play using chrome on the emulator could this be the main problem ?